# What is the arbitrary point that is referenced in System.nanoTime Javadoc?

Tags: java, time

I understand that `System.nanoTime()` has no relation to the epoch (which is related to `System.currentTimeMillis()` though).

From the Javadoc it states that the value returned from `System.nanoTime()` is an offset from some arbitrary point in time (may even be the future).

With regard to this

1. Is this point in time constant across JVM instances on the same platform?
2. Is this point in time constant across JVM instances across platforms?

If suppose I run my application and persist the value of `System.nanoTime()` into a file. Next I reexecute my application and compute the difference between the value in the file and the new value returned from `System.nanoTime()`.

Then is it safe to assume that the difference is the actual amount of time between the executions?

It would be if the arbitrary point in time would remain the same.

However I am not sure is that's the behavior

Answer (score 8):

No, it's arbitrary. Don't rely upon it being any given value, as it is not specified to work in that way. As it says [in the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime()):

> The same origin is used by all invocations of this method in an instance of a Java virtual machine; other virtual machine instances are likely to use a different origin.

`System.nanoTime()` is used to measure *elapsed* time on a single JVM, so you only care about the difference in its value between two invocations. Thus, knowing the offset isn't necessary.

Comment: Do you mean single execution of the JVM? Does the arbitrary value change when I start an new instance of the JVM?

Comment: If you run a different JVM, it's an "other virtual machine instance", so it is "likely to use a different origin".

Comment: Oh is it.  Guess then is it not safer to comparer the values returned from System.nanoTime() across application executions (even though both use the same JRE)

Answer (score 4):

The *implementation* of `nanoTime` is very platform specific. For instance, it depends on which high-resolution timers are available on your platform (if there is none, the result is just what `currentTimeMillis` times 10^6)
And even for a given platform and if you know which implementation is used, you must consider that the timer resets if the computer or even process is restarted.

So, **no**, you can't store the value in a file and use it later in any meaningful way.

Source: https://blogs.oracle.com/dholmes/entry/inside_the_hotspot_vm_clocks
In particular this paragraph

> #### Clocks and Timers on Windows
>
> System.nanoTime() is implemented using the
>   QueryPerformanceCounter/QueryPerformanceFrequency API (if available,
>   else it returns currentTimeMillis*10\^6).
>   QueryPerformanceCounter(QPC) is implemented in different ways
>   depending on the hardware it's running on. Typically it will use
>   either the programmable-interval-timer (PIT), or the ACPI power
>   management timer (PMT), or the CPU-level timestamp-counter (TSC).
>   ...

Microsoft about the QPC: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dn553408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

> QPC is independent of and isn't synchronized to any external time
>   reference.
>   ...
>
> QPC is typically the best method to use to time-stamp events and
>   measure small time intervals that occur on the same system or virtual
>   machine.
>   ...

It's safe to assume that the same limitations apply to Linux systems.